# Difference between loading the driver and registering drivers

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection

I am very new to JDBC, and I have written a small program to check the drivers registered. I wanted to do the following

1. I checked the number of registers without loading any drivers:

   I was expecting it to give nothing to my surprise it gives 3 drivers registered.
2. I loaded a driver using Class.forName();

   I was expecting it to show me four drivers yet again got a shock, it shows 3 drivers only
3. Lastly I register the driver using DriverManager

   Now it shows four drivers.

Could anyone help me in understanding what is happening here.  My question are the following

1. Are these three drivers loaded/registered by default.
2. Won't loading the class using `Class.forName` register the driver? (I guess the answer is not for this as from my experience, I am asking this just to be sure) if no then is loading the class just to seek the implementation of the inferfaces like(DriverManager etc...)
3. Lastly what is the difference between loading the driver and register the driver

I have listed both the program and the output for your reference.

```
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;

class Test3{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

     //checking for registered drivers
     System.out.println("Drivers registered initially");
     Enumeration enumm = DriverManager.getDrivers();
     int count=1;
     while(enumm.hasMoreElements()){
         Driver dr=(Driver)enumm.nextElement();
         System.out.println(count+" "+dr);
         count++;
     }

     //loading the driver
     Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
     System.out.println("\n\nDrivers after class loading");
     enumm = DriverManager.getDrivers();
     count=1;
     while(enumm.hasMoreElements()){
         Driver dr=(Driver)enumm.nextElement();
         System.out.println(count+" "+dr);
         count++;
     }

     //After Registering driver
     OracleDriver odr= new OracleDriver();
     DriverManager.registerDriver(odr);
     System.out.println("\nAfter registering oracle driver");
     enumm = DriverManager.getDrivers();
     count=1;
     while(enumm.hasMoreElements()){
         Driver dr=(Driver)enumm.nextElement();
         System.out.println(count+" "+dr);
         count++;
     }

}
}
```

Output:

```
Drivers registered initially
```

1 sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver@2c84d9

2 oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver@8bdcd2

3 com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@1f31ad9

```
Drivers after class loading
```

1 sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver@2c84d9

2 oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver@8bdcd2

3 com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@1f31ad9

```
After registering oracle driver
```

1 sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver@2c84d9

2 oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver@8bdcd2

3 com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@1f31ad9

4 oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver@167acf2

Comment: Which JDK do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from JDK6 onward the JDBC drivers automatically get loaded if JVM found any Driver class in classpath. There is no need of Class.forName statement in JDK6. That's why you are getting drivers because they werein your classpath and loaded by JVM.

Comment: I am using Jdk-7.. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: This is only true for JDBC 4 compliant drivers that have the required services definition in their jar (so old drivers or not-compliant drivers are not (always) loaded automatically).

Comment: I meant the feature was added in JDK6 so definitely it will be same in JDK 7 .. check the link here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13157_01/wlevs/docs30/jdbc_drivers/usedriver.html

Comment: Yes I do have some jar files in reference libraries. on removing that the output has reduced to just 

1 sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver@16fd0b7. So can i consider that odbc driver is loaded y default.

Comment: Class.forName("..."). loads the class, but does loading the class using forName, even register the driver in DriverManager?

Comment: Yes, It is default comes with runtime.

Comment: When it will be load it will also register .. don't worry ... when Driver class will load it will execute a static block that will register that driver.

Comment: read JDBC 4.0 feature in this link http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/08/02/jjdbc-4-enhancements-in-java-se-6.html

Comment: I shall surely go through it. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The JDBC specification requires that compliant drivers register themselves with `java.sql.DriverManager` when they are loaded (using a static initializer block). You should **never** have to register a driver yourself.

Starting from JDBC 4.0 (Java 6), JDBC drivers are required to specify a services definition declaring all `java.sql.Driver` implementations provided by the driver (usually one). This is done through a file `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`.

The `DriverManager` will query all instances of this file on the classpath (using [`java.util.ServiceLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) and load all driver implementations contained in these files. As a (compliant) driver is required to register itself, all these implementations are now registered with `DriverManager`.

So:

1. It is no longer necessary to use `Class.forName(...);` to load a driver (unless the driver is not JDBC 4 compliant)
2. You should never have to manually register a driver with `DriverManager` (unless the driver is not JDBC 1 compliant, or was specifically built to not register itself)

In your specific code you have three JDBC 4 compliant drivers (at least with regard to the services definition) so they are loaded automatically. Executing `Class.forName(..)` has no effect because the class is already loaded (so it won't be loaded again). When you manually register a driver (which as I said before, you should **never** do), it will add an additional instance to the list of registered drivers.

Comment: "JDBC 1 compliant," ?

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub The requirement for drivers to register themselves with `DriverManager` was already specified in the first JDBC specification, hence "JDBC 1 compliant".